# Display a time but have it change based on location

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, time

I want to enter a local time (e.g. 10:00am) on a Worpress website in a normal text box and have that time change to the local time of the current user.
Is this possible?

Comment: In a textbox? Why in a textbox? Anyway, if you create a timestamp for your location and display it, JS/the browser will auto-convert it to local time. Is this about online business hours?

Comment: I want to add a time for a local event in the future in a post, but have this local time converted to the local "users" time. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, of course. I was just confused by the "text box" part. Anyway, you need to convert your local time to UTC, then use `setUTCHours()` to set up a Date object. Outputting it will now convert to user's system time: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1fov86kL/

Comment: Do you want to do it in PHP? How is the "future time" set in your post; with a meta field?